# How to understand Caffe reshape parameters and reimplement in Keras?

Tags: neural-network, keras, caffe, reshape, layer

I am not sure how to interpret the reshape parameters. here http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/layers/reshape.html it says that 0 means copy and -1 means infer. Is it the same when -1 is not the last parameter ? Can anyone help me understand it?

```
 layer {
  name: "Layer1"
  type: "Reshape"
  bottom: "Layer1"
  top: "Layer2"
  reshape_param {
  shape {
      dim: 0
      dim: 2
      dim: -1
      dim: 0
}
}
```

Also, if I want to implement the same layer in Keras, do I also use the Keras reshape layer like :

```
Layer2 = K.reshape(Layer1,(-1,input_dim))
```

Comment: See [this good documentation](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/reshape.html) about `"Reshape"` layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that considering you have an input of shape `(a, b, c, d, e)`, your output will have shape:

```
(a, 2, b * c * e / 2, d)
```

The values `a` and `d` are copied from the previous layer. The value 2 is forced, and the value `-1` calculates whatever it needs to keep the same number of elements as the input.

In Keras, since you're not changing the first dimension (the batch size), you only need a regular Reshape layer that will ignore the batch size:

```
Reshape((2,-1,youMustKnowThis))
```

In a `Sequential` model, just add this layer:

```
sequentialModel.add(Reshape((2,-1,youMustKnowThis))
```

In a functional API `Model`, pass the output of the previous layer:

```
newShaped = Reshape((2,-1,youMustKnowThis))(outputOfPreviousLayer)
```